# Interfacing strace with Process Name instead of PID

Tags: bash, process, pid, strace, tracing

How do I implement a wrapper script `pstrace` in bash that changes the interface of

```
[sudo] strace -c -p [PID]
```

to

```
[sudo] pstrace -c -p [PROCESS-NAME]
```

similar to how

```
killall [PROCESS-NAME]
```

is used. With completion and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 5.15, strace can print the command/process names:

- Implemented `--decode-pids=comm` option (and its alias `-Y`) for printing
  command names for PIDs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Thy this:

```
ps auxw | grep [PROCESS-NAME] | awk '{print"-p " $2}' | xargs strace
```

Answer (score 2):

Deceptively complicated requirements :-)

In two parts, firstly the `pstrace` wrapper script for `strace`, this uses `pgrep` for the name-to-PID operation.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$' \t\n'

# process the arguments to find "-p procname", only support one instance though
for ((nn=1; nn<=$#; nn++)); do
    if [ "${!nn}" = "-p" ]; then
        :
    elif [ "$prev" = "-p" ]; then
        pname="${!nn}"
    else
        args+=( "${!nn}" )    # just copy 
    fi
    prev="${!nn}"
done

pids=()
if [ -n "$pname" ]; then
    # skip this shell's PID, which pgrep -f will match
    # note the use of exec to avoid picking up a matching subshell too
    # uncomment  && printf for pid/pname list
    while read pp pname; do 
         [ "$pp" != "$$" ] && pids+=($pp) # && printf "%6i %s\n" "$pp" "$pname"
    done < <(exec pgrep -l -f "${pname}")
fi

npids=${#pids[*]}

if [ $npids -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No PIDs to trace."; exit 2
elif [ $npids -eq 1 ]; then
    args=( "${args[@]}" -p ${pids[0]} )
elif [ $npids -le 32 ]; then
    read -p "$npids PIDS found, enter Y to proceed: " yy
    [ "$yy" != "Y" ] && echo "Cancelled..." && exit 1
    args=( "${args[@]}" ${pids[@]/#/-p } ) 
else 
    echo "Too many PIDs to trace: $npids (max 32)."; exit 2
fi 

strace "${args[@]}"
```

For the second part I'll use `bash` programmable completion to complete processes by name, put this in your `~/.bash_profile` or similar:

```
# process-name patterns to ignore
PROCIGNORE=( "^\[", "^-bash" )

_c8n_listprocs ()
{
    local cur prv ignore IFS nn mm
    prv=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

    case "$prv" in
        '-p') 
              IFS=$'\n' COMPREPLY=( $(ps axwwo "args") ) IFS=$' \t\n'
              COMPREPLY=(${COMPREPLY[*]// */})  # remove arguments

              ignore="0" # ps header
              for ((nn=1; nn<${#COMPREPLY[*]}; nn++)); do
                  # filter by (partially) typed name in cur
                  # use  " =~ ^$cur " for prefix match, without ^ it's substr match
                  [[ -n "$cur"  &&  ! "${COMPREPLY[$nn]}" =~ $cur ]] && {
                      ignore="$nn $ignore"
                  } || { 
                      # skip names matching PROCIGNORE[]
                      for ((mm=0; mm<${#PROCIGNORE[*]}; mm++)); do
                          [[ "${COMPREPLY[$nn]}" =~ ${PROCIGNORE[$mm]} ]] && 
                              ignore="$nn $ignore"
                      done
                  }
              done
              # remove unwanted, in reverse index order
              for nn in $ignore; do unset COMPREPLY[$nn]; done

              ;;
        *)    COMPREPLY=()
              ;;
    esac
}
complete -F _c8n_listprocs pstrace
```

Tested & used on linux with bash-3.x and bash-4.x. `ps` options may need tweaking on non-Linux platforms, should also support `truss` with a one-line change.

Limitations include:

- no correct escaping of kernel-thread like process `[names]`, this will cause `pgrep` to (likely) not do what you want
- mismatched of processes with space in the name ("`args`" is used instead of "`comm`" so that `/paths` can be used , where available)